# DIfference between removing a column and making it hidden in Content Type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have dealt with a customer recently where i suggested to hide some fields in content type to decrease loading time(I am not sure this might help him). But he asked me what would be the difference between removing the field from the specific Content Type and making it hidden, and the implications. Any share of knowledge/link is much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please tell us more about where exactly do you want to 'decrease loading time' ?

Comment: My colleague suggested that when the field is hidden(lookup), it would decrease some loading time in new form as the lookup doesnt need to load options from another list.

Answer (score 0):

First, if I don't use a field, I'll definitely try to remove it. It's not a good habit to have some trash hidden field in Content Type. We often have some difficult to keep a clean structure with unique fields, content types... So when you have the opportunity so simplify this, just do it.

However, if your Customer want to keep the data in the column, hide the field is a solution.

I don't think there is more to say about these 2 options.

*Edit : Sorry if it is a little bit confusing. By deleting, I mean remove the field in your list. This'll just remove the local column in the list not the column definition in the site settings.*

Comment: Do you mean to say, if a column is removed from content type, it would be deleted? I think it will still be in site columns. Isn't that so?

Comment: Keep it in site columns but remove it from content type